# Run unit tests on local server within a Gulp task

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp, html5-history

I'm trying to run automated unit tests in the terminal for an application library that uses the History API internally. I am using Babel to transpile and merge my unit tests (written using Mocha/Chai/Sinon) to a single test file. I then open a local HTML file (that includes that test file) into Headless Chrome to run the tests. This all worked fine.

I first run into trouble when Headless Chrome throws errors because I'm using the `pushState` method of the History API on a local file. The exact error message is:

> Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/code/projects/app/test/foo' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///C:/code/projects/app/test/runner.html'.

So, I install gulp-connect to run a local server that starts at the beginning of the gulp task and is closed at the end of the task (I don't want a persistent connection). I reconfigure everything to work through the server and when I run the Gulp task, the previous error is gone.

The problem is the terminal no longer prints the results of the unit tests. Gulp tells me the task starts and finishes, but nothing else. It gives the impression that the tests are passing even if I intentionally add a test that will fail.

Any idea what's going on here? I thought this would be a pretty straight forward transition, which leads me to believe I'm doing something stupid (a common occurrence). I'm not opposed to moving away from Gulp (to NPM scripts for example) if it fixes the issue. The end-goal is to have this be an automated process that I can run manually and Travis CI can run on each push to the public repo.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by switching to Karma.